# Pocket Door Slow Close: Super smooth when closing, but hard to open

Tags: pocket-door

I replaced an old school pocket door track with [one of these tracks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KJRP3HF).

It's really smooth when it closes, but it's a bit tough to open (tough enough that the wife has complained about it already). You need a directed effort to open it.

Is there a common approach to reducing the tension with these slow close features? Move slow close further back away so it only partly engages? Reduce spring tension in some way?

Comment: You just need the setup used on the USS Enterprise NC-1701 where the doors just swoosh back hands-free as you approach them. ;^) More seriously, are there any adjustments on the closer (screw heads, nuts, etc. - hopefully they would be documented, but if it has a relationship with other sorts of "door closer" there's usually some way to limit force and speed built in.)

Comment: The law of conservation of energy at work. That slow-close feature needs to be charged for each retraction. That's how it happens, and that's why I haven't installed them on my kitchen drawers. I'm not aware of them being adjustable.